# Is it mandatory for upgrade to EF Core 6 while migrating .NET Core3.1 to .NET 6

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-2.2, asp.net-core-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I have a asp.net core web api project with .NET Core 3.1 target framework. This project uses Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 2.2.6. I migrated the entire web api project from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET Core 6.  The project compiled fine including its dependencies without any issues. I did minimum validations and found no issues .I still wanted to know is it mandatory to migrate Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore from 2.2.6 to 6.0

Can anyone provide their guidance regarding this scenario?

Comment: No, it's not. Apart from missing out on new features and fixes, you're ok as long as the code compiles and works. In my case, I was able to stay in EF 2.1 while upgrading to .NET Core 3.1, because a database driver wasn't yet available for EF 3.1. It worked fine without problems. Then when the driver came out, I also upgraded EF to 3.1.

Comment: Thanks @abdusco for your response. In this context my target version is .NET Core 6.Intially we updated the EFCore version from 2.2.6 to 6.0. But I am getting runtime errors